# How to pause stopwatch in windows phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, stopwatch

I am working on timer - stopwatch( 00:00:00 hrs:min:sec) . When I select play button, the timer runs.It's fine. When I select pause, the timer should get paused and the values should posted in a listbox into the next screen. play and stop are easy to do. but how to pause timer?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.Stop()` you're acctually pausing stopwatch:

```
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    stopwatch.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds); //Elapsed time will be 4 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this sample app I wrote here :
http://www.algotutor.com/stopwatch-timer-app-windows-phone/